# Batch script copy folder using wildcard

Tags: batch-file, recursion, wildcard, xcopy

I need to copy a folder matching a wildcard, for instance FOLDER_*. That folder will be in the presence of other files, so I need the command to segregate it from everything else. Also, the command needs to recursively search through the directory, and return only the FOLDER that matches the wildcard, with its contents intact. Then it needs to copy it to another folder. Any ideas? I've tried quite a few variants - here is the last thing I tried.

`for /D /R %%f in (FOLDER_*) do xcopy %%f %~dp0\TestResults`

Comment: Your code should work (it does here), so what exactly is the problem? Does it find two FOLDER_* items?

Comment: Why not use `DIR /ad /b` assigned to a variable to do the copying?  You can also use `DIR /ad /b /s` to search recursively.

Comment: The code I have above ends up copying the contents of the folders, but doesn't keep them in their respective folders. user4317867, can you elaborate on your suggestion. If so, I will give it a try.

Comment: This code seems to copy the folder structure, but not the file contents.

Comment: for /D /R %%f in (FOLD_*) do xcopy /t /e /a /s %%f\.. %~dp0\TestResults

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet should copy all found `FOLDER_*` folders including their subfolders but omits all their parent folder(s) like `upfolder\` in `upfolder\FOLDER_*` (however could be improved to include it, of course).
`for /F` loop against `dir /b /s /ad` (a static list of subfolders) is used instead of `for /D /R` as the option `/d /r` is undocumented.
Pay your attention to recursion like `FOLDER_main\FOLDER_sub1\FOLDER_sub11` etc.
Operational `mkdir` and `xcopy` commands are merely `echo`ed for debugging purposes only:

```
@echo OFF
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /S /AD FOLDER_*') do (
  echo mkdir "%~dp0\TestResults\%%~nxf" 2>NUL
  echo xcopy /S /E /C "%%~ff" "%~dp0\TestResults\%%~nxf\"
)
```

Consider adding more switches to `xcopy`, for instance

- `/H` Copies hidden and system files also.
- `/R` Overwrites read-only files.
- `/Y` Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.